# How to set up github notification correctly?

Tags: github

I worked with gitlab before and the notification settings there were extremely clear. Now I need to work in several teams in github.

Faced with the problem of a huge number of emails from the repositories of the team.
I would like notifications to come only on my pull requests and that's it.

Now I have the setting enabled "Participating, @mentions and custom".

How can I set this up in the easiest way?